# Calculate the value of $G$ as a combined proportions of $A$, $B$ and $C$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, nonlinear-dynamics

I have been tasked with an exercise that looks simple but now I have some doubts and I would like to get another opinion.

*G* is related with *A*, *B* and *C* in the following way.

```
      _G_
   +/     \-
   /       \
+/  \+   +/  \-
A    B   C    B
```

- When $A$ and $B$ increase $G$ increases
- When $C$ increases and $B$ decreases, $G$ decreases
- The effect of $B$ on $A$ and $C$ is asymmetric. An increase of $B$ on $A$ makes $G$ increase at a much faster rate. On the other hand, an increase in $C$ would cause $G$ to decrease but at a much lower rate.
- The value of $A$, $B$ and $C$ go from 0 to 1.

As an example, let's say that $A=0.8$  $B=0.012$  $C=0.9$. How would you calculate $G$?
I would be tempted to simply say

$G=\frac{AB}{\sqrt{C}}$

but I think I missing something since it looks like this is a combined proportions problem.

Comment: There are infinitely many formulas meeting your specifications, and you have given no way to tell which one you want. $AB-C$ also works, so does $A^2B^3/C^4$, and $e^A\log B-\sqrt C$, and ....

Comment: Any thoughts, user?

Comment: Dear @GerryMyerson, I have gathered more information and updated the question. Thank you very much for your interest.

Comment: Still doesn't pin it down much. What do you mean by "a combined proportions problem"?

Comment: I mean that the quantity G depends on N other quantities with N=3 (A, B,C)

Comment: OK, well, in your example, $G=AB/\sqrt C$, $G$ does depend on the three quantities $A,B,C$. So, why do you think you're missing something?

Comment: I think the formula I am using doesn't incorporate the idea of asymmetry in the relationship... but maybe it is. What's your opinion?

Comment: My opinion is that I don't think you've made your idea of asymmetry very precise.

Comment: I cannot go further than this based on my information. As you said there might be multiple solutions.